# How to obtain dynamic form data using request.get for Google App Engine

Tags: jquery, python, forms, google-app-engine, webapp2

i am building a dynamic form to capture the user input of currency pairs. For example, EUR/USD; CHF/USD, etc.

I have created a dynamic form for the user to add on currency pair that they want. The form looks like this (without CSS):

[image]

In the code, i JQuery to create a name of currency_n_1/currency_n_2 for nth currency pair.

The form is:

```
<form method="post" id="parentForm">
    <label>Please select your currency</label>
    <br>
    <div id="currency_1">
        <select name="currency_1_1" id="currency_1_1">
            <option>SGD</option>
            <option>CNY</option>
            <option>USD</option>
            <option>EUR</option>
        </select> 
        <select name="currency_1_2" id="currency_1_2">
            <option>SGD</option>
            <option>CNY</option>
            <option>USD</option>
            <option>EUR</option>
        </select> 
        <br>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="add_button" value="Add Currency">
    <input type="button" value="remove" id="remove_button">
</form>
```

And the Jquery is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("JQ working")
    var index = 1;
    var index_1 = 2;
    var currency_pair = [];

    // Create a remove button
    var remove_1 = $('<input type="button" value="remove" id="remove_button">');

    $("#add_button").click(function(){
        console.log(index);
        var remove = $('<input />', {type:'button', value:'Remove',  id:'remove_'+index_1 });
        $("#currency_"+index).after($("#currency_"+index).clone().attr({"name":"currency_"+index_1, "id":"currency_"+index_1}));
        $("#currency_"+index_1).css("display","inline");
        $("#currency_"+index_1).children('#currency_'+index+'_1').attr({"name":"currency_"+index_1+"_1","id":"currency_"+index_1+"_1"});

        $("#currency_"+index_1).children('#currency_'+index+'_2').attr({"name":"currency_"+index_1+"_2","id":"currency_"+index_1+"_2"});
        $("#currency_"+index_1).children('#remove_'+index).attr({"name":"remove_"+index_1,"id":"remove_"+index_1});
        if (index==1) {
            console.log("noew index is 1")
            $("#currency_"+index_1 +"_2").after(remove);
        };
        index = index + 1;
        index_1 = index + 1;
        console.log(index);

        $("#remove_"+index).click(function(){
            //Remove the whole cloned div
            console.log("remove working")
            $(this).closest("div").remove();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**So each currency pair would have a name of currency_n_1 and currency_n_2**.

But I don't know how do i suppose to get the data using request.get, if only one pair of currency

```
    def post(self):
        user_currency_1_1 = self.request.get('currency_1_1')
        user_currency_1_2 = self.request.get('currency_1_2')
```

**But i actually don't know how many pairs have the user submitted. So how can i make sure that obtained all the currency pairs when user submit this dynamic form?**

Answer (score 0):

I would use `react` or similar for this.  But you can do it in plain javascript.  Essentially, you build a JSON object in the client web page, maintaining a list of each of the `n`pairs.  Use `onchange` events to update the list then update the DOM where they appear.  All the work is done on the client side, in the browser.  Much cleaner as you don't need to worry about the indexing (`'#currency_' + index + '_1'`).  A list is ordered automatically.  Use standard list methods: `push()`, `slice()`, `splice()`, etc. and assignments to modify the list in the browser.

At submit, you just send over the JSON object in the request, then loop through it in the backend to do whatever you need.